# implement a modal window, which still lets the user navigate on the page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog, livechat

I am currently adding a live chat to my webapp. I got it already finished - now to the problem:

I want the live-chat to "stick" to the down right edge part of my webapplication. I want it to still persist, when there is a route-change for example - so the user can still navigate on the page and still do whatever he wants.

I googled already for modal windows, that "follow", but I cant find any results.

How can I accomplish that behaviour of my live chat? (modal window dialog?)
What do I need to search for?

Comment: Just create a div element with `position: fixed` and a high z-index.

Comment: @Fussel   I think that it isnt that easy after all. My project has many more components, so when doing this in a component and changing the route, it would vanish, wouldnt it?

Comment: You have to create the chat component outside of the `router-outlet` component, than it will not vanish when navigating. Asuming you are creating a spa

Comment: What if you put the modal component in the app-component, outside of the router?

Comment: @Raffael the problem is, that I need to "trigger" that live chat in my specific component - therefore I just cant put it in the app-component

Comment: Why not use a service with a subscriber to trigger the opening? And import that service in app component.

Comment: @Raffael sounds like a good idea!  that should mean, that the window will still persist, if im correct. ill have a look into it, thanks!

Comment: It will persist if done correctly, seeing as the routing only takes place inside router-outlet. Good luck